# Maximum flow bipartite with intermediate nodes

Tags: algorithm, networking, graph, max-flow

I'm working on a problem where one is to create a exam schedule based on some constraints by creating a flow network.

- A set number of courses C
- A set number of days D
- A set number of rooms R
- A mapping of students S to their courses

If a student is taking course c1  and c2, the two exams cannot be held at the same time.

I'm having trouble creating a flow network from these constraints. 
This is one of the networks I've tried to make so far.
[image: Flow Network]

Black nodes are source and sink.
Red are students.
Green are courses.
Orange are days.
Blue are rooms.

The numbers represent the flow capacity.

After creating the appropriate flow graph, I know I would use the Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm to find the max flow.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a flow problem.  It's actually NP-complete; you can reduce the graph colouring problem to it as follows:

Take as the set of courses the vertex set of the graph in your graph colouring instance.  For each edge in that graph, say between `u` and `v`, create a student who's taking only courses `u` and `v`.  Have exactly as many time slots as there are colours available.

Then a feasible schedule (where no student has both of his exams at the same time) will be a colouring of your graph.

You might have better luck building an integer programming model of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of this being a graph colouring problem definitely came to mind. The problem is that using a graph colouring approach wouldn't help me actually determine a feasible schedule, it would only tell me that one existed.

Comment: @YamatoC: You can formulate this as a colouring problem where a feasible colouring maps directly to a feasible assignment of courses to days.  You have the additional constraint that you can't have too many rooms happen on a given day.  If that winds up being a problem, you should really do an IP model instead of a straight colouring model.  (Symmetries will slow solution time, but it will at least work.)